# Any experiences with automatically playing videos one after the other whilst embedded in a webpage?

Tags: python, django, html, web

So I'm newish to web dev as well as using django. A friend of mine is in film and is interested in embedding a bunch of clips in a webpage for a project of hers that would play one after the other.

What I mean by one after the other is that once one ends another video automatically starts up.

Does anyone have any guidance or experience with the best way for me to make this happen? Or are there any plugins I might find useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can try jPlayer: http://jplayer.org/
Just add a listener to the `$.jPlayer.event.ended` event to start the next video.
See: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-event-type